# Dump a list into a JSON file acceptable by Athena

Tags: json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am creating a JSON file in an s3 bucket using the following code -

```
def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
    return o.__str__()
s3.put_object(
            Bucket='sample-bucket',
            Key="sample.json",
            Body = json.dumps(whole_file, default=myconverter)
            
        )
```

Here, the whole_file variable is a list.
Sample of the "whole_file" variable -

```
[{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"},{"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}]
```

The output "sample.json" file that I get should be in the following format -

```
{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"}
{"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}
```

The output "sample.json" that I am getting is -

```
[{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"},{"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}]
```

What changes should be made to get each JSON object in a single line?

Answer (score 0):

You can write each entry to the file, then upload the file object to s3

```py
import json
whole_file = [{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"},
              {"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}
             ]

with open("temp.json", "w") as temp:
    for record in whole_file:
        temp.write(json.dumps(record, default=str))
        temp.write("\n")
```

The lookput should look like this

```sh
~ cat temp.json
{"sample_column1": "abcd", "sample_column2": "efgh"}
{"sample_column1": "ijkl", "sample_column2": "mnop"}
```

upload the file

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.upload_file("temp.json", bucket, object_name="whole_file.json")
```